# Firebase Auth getCurrent user returns true for != null even though the user is not logged in! here i want to change intent only once user logs in

Tags: android, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

```
        import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
        import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private ImageButton mSendata;
            private Firebase mRef; // database connection
            private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            private TextView email;
            private TextView password;
            private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

            @Override
  //runs when activity created
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
                password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.password);
                mRef = new Firebase("https://notifyme-dfed3.firebaseio.com/");
                mSendata = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    // Auth change method
                mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
```

// having problem here-----------------------------------------------------

```
                        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountActivity.class));
                        }


                    }


                };
```

//--------------------end-- please check within comments------------------------------------------------

```
                mSendata.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            startSignIn(); //calls sign in method when user clicks button

                        }


                    });
            }

            protected void onStart() {
                super.onStart();
                mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
            }
```

//This method signs in the user

```
            public void startSignIn() {


                String emails = email.getText().toString();/* gets user input*/
                String passwords = password.getText().toString();
```

// check if fields are empty

```
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(emails) || TextUtils.isEmpty(passwords)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emails, passwords).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < AuthResult > () {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < AuthResult > task) {                       /* if task not success show dialog

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });

                }
            }


        }// end of code
```

Comment: So if `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()` is not null, then what is it?

Comment: If `onAuthStateChanged` fires with a current user, it clearly thinks there's a signed in current user. What makes you think there isn't?

Comment: **intent** switches directly without login form! could there be any simple fix @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: In my case the situation is even more stranger... it is considering some user which I had created for testing and doesn't exist any more. One more strange thing is that its happening even when I install the app freshly. This default user is being removed only when I clear the app data. I'm not able to understand from where is this user being fetched by firebase.

Comment: @AbhijithShenoy how did you solve your problem?

Comment: I have given answer to this problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54858484/3904109  please see that...

Answer (score 0):

In Your Manifest File Add The Following
In the `<manifest>` tag (at the end)

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Then in the `<application>` tag (at the begining)

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
android:allowBackup="false"
android:fullBackupContent="false"
```

This was a problem I faced so much, I have already answered it https://stackoverflow.com/a/54858484/3904109 but am reposting it here so that people here can get the benefit.  just as @Doug Stevenson mentioned above firebase saves some data on the phone adding these tags will ensure that that does not happen... so when you uninstall the app and install it again it will clear all the data associated with the app.